# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arccos

Tags: python, numpy, trigonometry

I am new to using Python but getting along with it fairly well. I keep getting the error you see below and not sure what the problem is exactly as I believe the values are correct and stated. What do you think the problem exactly is? I am trying to graph from t = 0 to t=PM, and the formula you see below is angle arccos.

Couldn't find the troubleshooting of this arccos error online. Running Python 3.5.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot
from __future__ import division

rE = 1.50*(10**11)
rM = 3.84*(10**8)
PE = 3.16*(10**7)
PM = 2.36*(10**6)

t = np.linspace(0, PM, 200)

# anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arccos
y = 0.5*(np.arccos(2*(np.pi)*t*((1/PM)-(1/PE))+90))
```

Comment: arccos is only defined in the range `[-1,1]`. See ["domain" in the numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arccos.html). You feed it a number > 1.

Comment: I came here because sometimes the input to arccos was only slightly larger than 1. (due to numerical precision). I solved it with np.arccos(np.minimum(1, array))

Comment: Alternative to @gota which accounts for negative values too: `np.arccos(np.around(array,4))`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you simplify to just

```py
np.arccos(90)
```

(which is the first element in the array being passed to arccos), you'll get the same warning

Why is that? `arccos()` attempts to solve **x** for which `cos(x) = 90`. However, such a value doesn't make sense as it's [outside of the possible domain for arccos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) `[-1,1]`

Also note that at least in recent versions of numpy, this calculation returns `nan`

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> b = np.arccos(90)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arccos
>>> b
nan
```

Comment: Silly of me! Should've known that! Guess there is an error in my calculations then. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8):

The `np.arccos()` function can only take values between `-1` and `1`, inclusive.

See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.arccos.html